# Idiomatic way to collect even to odd elements from a list to map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to get a map from a list where all even elements should become keys and all odds - values:

```
val elements = listOf("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3")
val myMap: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
for (i in elements.indices step 2) {
    myMap[elements[i]] = elements[i + 1]
}
```

Is there any more idiomatic way to do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code:

```kotlin
val elements = listOf("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3")

val map = elements.chunked(2) { it[0] to it[1] }.toMap()

println(map)
```

Output:

```
{k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v3}
```

Comment: Found out how to apply this idea to a list with an odd number of elements: 1) to associate the last key with the null: `elements.chunked(2) { it[0] to it.elementAtOrNull(1) }.toMap()`, 2) to drop the last key with no value: `elements.windowed(2, 2, false) { it[0] to it[1] }.toMap()`